# How to create divs with dynamic id onclick a button in angular 6/7

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular 6,I need to create divs on click a button.The newly div created each time should be having different ids inside container.Here is the code below

### app.html

```
<button (click)="creatediv()">Create div</button>
<div  class="container">
 <div id="div1">Newly div created</div>
<div  id="div2">Newly div created</div>
</div>
```

### app.ts

```
creatediv() {

  }
```

Comment: This is clearly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You've decided this is the path to go down, but _really_ you probably do not care about the IDs, you care about different `(click)` events.  Why don't you reframe the question to include what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array in your component `.ts` and iterate over this in your template:

template:

```
<button (click)="createDiv()">Create div</button>
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let div of divs" id="div{{div}}">Newly div created</div>
</div>
```

component:

```
export class DivsComponent {
  divs: number[] = [];

  createDiv(): void {
    this.divs.push(this.divs.length);
  }
}
```

for reverse order you can change the createDiv method to this:

```
createDiv(): void {
  this.divs.unshift(this.divs.length);
}
```

Comment: @cale_b the onclick portion is there though :) but I understand what you are saying. I just hope there is a reason for the `ids`. Perhaps a scroll anchor of such sort

Comment: Thanks for your answer,its working fine,Can we create the div in reverse order,now its creating with id,div0,div1,div2 ..I need to create div2,div1,div0, I mean current div will come top,I used reverse in ngfor but its not working

Comment: @carreankush I've updated my answer. Basically you use the `unshift` method, instead of `push`